# Modulo 10^9 + 7 of a user scanned number

Tags: c, casting, overflow, modulo

I have a digit stored in a variable count. I have to scan a number N (upto size 10^18) and then multiply the variable count with 10^(N-2) and then compute its modulo (10^9 + 7). I tried to do this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int T,w;
    char ch='0';
    unsigned long long int M=1000000007;

    unsigned long long int i,N,count;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    while(T--)
    {
        scanf("%llu %d",&N,&w);

           if(w==0 || w==-1)
            count=9;
           else if(w==1 || w==-2)
            count=8;
          else if(w==2 || w==-3)
            count=7;
           else if(w==3 || w==-4)
             count=6;
        else if(w==4 || w==-5)
            count=5;
            else if(w==5 || w==-6)
            count=4;
            else if(w==6 || w==-7)
            count=3;
           else if(w==7 || w==-8)
            count=2;
            else if(w==8 || w==-9)
            count=1;
           else
           count=0;
        count = count*pow(10,N-2)%M;
        printf("%llu\n",count);

     }
}
```

But, 1)since pow returns double and % wants both its operands to be int, it gives a compilation error 2)Typecasting won't help because no data type can store a value of the size
(10)^(10^18)

How do I get through this?

Comment: Don't use float functions when working with integers.

Comment: `(10)^(10^18)` cannot be stored in a `long long` either - or even a `double` for that matter.  Did you mean `10 * 10^18` instead?

Comment: @Clifford No. I meant (10)^(10^18). I am just not able to multiply my variable count with a user given number N(which can be as big as 10^(10^18)) and then take its modulo 10^9 + 7. Can you innovate some way to do so?

Comment: The user given number cannot be as large as  10^(10^18)) if it is an unsigned long long.  I'd like to tell you how many bits you'd need to store an integer that large, but no calculator will handle numbers that large.  Given that it is 1 and 10^18 zeros, suffice it to say your computer has insufficient memory to store such a value.

Comment: @Clifford Thank you so much.I think I need to store that number in an array

Comment: @RizwanAnsari : how is that going to work?  You cannot have an array long enough on any existing computer, and could not process it in your lifetime. Think about it!

Comment: The title asks a different question than the text, and the code has a different calculation from either. Voting to close and unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Considering that [the total estimated mass of the known universe would correspond to 10^80 hydrogen atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe#Matter_content_%E2%80%93_number_of_atoms), it will be hard to find more bits than that. So brute force might not be the solution here.

Comment: @Clifford `log(10) * (10 ^ 18)` bits :)

Comment: @Clifford by `log(10)` I meant `log-base-2`  not `log-base-10`.

Answer (score 0):

Just create your own integer pow funtion, or in this case more simply  an integer exp10 function:

```
unsigned long long exp10i( unsigned n )
{
    unsigned long long e = 1 ;
    for( unsigned p = 0; i < n; p++ )
    {
        e *= 10u ;
    }

    return e ;
}
```

Then:

```
count = (count * exp10i( N-2 )) % M;
```

Comment: e is still an int, it can't store such large values when N=10^18

Comment: still, even long long int can't store 10^(10^18)

Comment: @RizwanAnsari : True, but your question does not ask for that, and your _entire computer_ could not hold such a value either.  Actually I stand corrected, your question does mention that - but that is not what your code does.  It is an unreasonable requirement.

Comment: @Clifford: It is entirely feasible to compute the requested residue modulo 10^9+7. This does not require using values larger than 64 bits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil : That is not what's in dispute.  The question and the code do not match.